# Regex that extracts text between tags, but not the tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to write a regex which extract the content that is between two tags `<title>` in a string but not the tags. 
IE I have the following

```
<title>My work</title>
<p>This is my work.</p> <p>Learning regex.</p>
```

The regex

```
(<title>)(.*?)(<\/title>)
```

extracts `<title>My work</title>` but I want to extract only `My work`. How can I do that?
This is a link to the example http://regex101.com/r/mD8fB0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this following Regex:

```
>([^<]*)<
```

or,   >[^<]*<

Then eliminate unwanted characters like '<' & '>'

Comment: can you explain the meaning of `[^<]` ?

Comment: This doesn't work with `<charlie><bob>Alice</bob></charlie>` - i.e. text inside nested tags. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AmitChoukroun `[]` means character or character group list, `^` in `[]` *specifically* means NOT, `*` means 0+ characters so in spoken english: "0-N characters that are any character except "<".

Comment: @PeterX it seems to work for me, but maybe you can try an alteration: `preg_match_all('/>([^<]+)</', "<charlie><bob>Alice</bob></charlie>", $matches);` , `$matches[1]` will contain the pure non-empty text matches

Answer (score 7):

the best way is to use Assertions, for your case, the regex would be:

```
(?<=\<title\>).*?(?=\<\/title\>)
```

for more details have a look [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Comment: this not work if newline character present in content!

Answer (score 5):

I used this as a replace function of Regex: (<.+?>)

Comment: SMART answer! I like the way you're looking at things

Answer (score 4):

In your case, you could just use the second backreference from the regex, which would hold the text you are interested in.

Since you mention `preg_match` in your tags, I am assuming you want this for PHP.

```
$matches = array();
$pattern = '#<title>(.*?)</title>#'; // note I changed the pattern a bit
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
$title = $matches[1];
```

Note that this is actually the first back reference in my patterns, since I've omitted the parentheses around the tags themselves, which were not needed.

Typically, you should not use Regex to parse HTML documents, but I think this might be one of those exception cases, where it is not so bad, since the title tag should only exist once on the page.