# Regular Expressions(extraction values)

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract content, between a certain text. 
For example:

`<html><title>lol</title></html>`
I want to extract what is located between the `<title> </ title>`, which regular expression do I need ?

Comment: If it is about html content, why not use a library like [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse HTML (except in the most constrained circumstances) has [unfortunate effects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/67392).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Have you glanced at other posts on the same topic? You could just modify a regular expression to your needs. For example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033905/regex-that-extracts-text-between-tags-but-not-the-tags) post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use better tools than regular expressions. 
Read about [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)

EDIT:
But if you want use regular expressions:

```
import re

def get_tag_body(tagname, text):
    regexp = r'<%s>(.*?)</%s>' % (tagname, tagname)
    rx_obj = re.search(regexp, text, re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
    return rx_obj.groups()
```