# How to get content between <td></td> only if no nested tags are present?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I realize there are loads of questions on getting something between something, even specifically HTML tags. But my requirement differs because I wan't ignore `<td></td>` content if nested tags are present. If there's still a duplicate, flag this and point me to that one.

**Sample input**: `<td><p>column1</p></td><td>column2</td>`
**Expected output**: column2 (awesome!) or >column2<

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033905/regex-that-extracts-text-between-tags-but-not-the-tags) question I tried `<td>(.*?)<\/td>` and got 2 matches:

```
<td><p>column1</p></td>
<td>column2</td>
```

As per marked answer, I tried `>[^<]*<` and got this:

[image]

That's close. I am Ok with getting > and < but I want regex to ignore 1st `<td>` because it has `<p>` nested inside it.

**Assumption**: `<p>` will always be the inner most tag in case of nesting. If input is `<td><p>column1</p>postfix</td>`, ignore such `<td>`.

Comment: You should not remove `td` from your regex - `<td\b[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/td>`

Comment: Don't try to parse HTML with a regular expression, see [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a regular expression to parse HTML as HTML is not a regular language. It's [*too complex to be parsed by regular expressions*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/257182).

What you can do is use the browser's built-in parser instead, then use DOM methods to get what you want.

```js
var s = '<td><p>column1</p></td><td>column2</td>'
var content = [];

// Create a row to insert the markup into
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
tr.innerHTML = s;

// Get the cells
var tds = tr.cells;

// If a cell doesn't have any element content, put its
// textContent into array
for (var i=0, iLen = tds.length; i<iLen; i++) {
 if (tds[i].children.length == 0) {
   content.push(tds[i].textContent);
 }
}

console.log(content);
```

Comment: Agreed and this looks easy and clean way. But this won't work for `<td><a>column2</a></td>`. Please note the requirement is to ignore `td` only if it has nested `p`. Rest should be picked up. So another loop for checking if `children` contain `<p>`! I'm following that path but seriously it's an overkill for what I am doing.

Comment: The restriction "*… only if it has nested p*" isn't clear in the OP, but `if (!tds[i].querySelector('p'))` will do the job. I don't see how any of the regular expression answers are restricted to ignoring only TDs with nested P elements.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var html='<td><p>column1</p></td><td>column2</td>';
var regex=/<td>([^<]*)<\/td>/ig;
var result=regex.exec(html);
console.info(result);
console.info(result[1]);
```

you can try this.result[1] is you want .
if you want to replace the content between tag,you can write like this too :

```js
     var html='<td><p>column1</p></td><td>column2</td>';
var regex=/<td>([^<]*)<\/td>/ig;
var newHtml=html.replace(regex,function(){
 return '<td>'+'replacement'+'</td>';
});
console.info(newHtml);
```

Comment: This correctly picks desired `td` but returns the tag as well. Note that I cant replace tags for a reason.

Comment: I want to replace part/whole content so if my search input is "td" it will replace `td` tags too. That will break things.

Comment: This regex does not match `<td><a>column2</a></td>`. Please note the requirement is to ignore `td` only if it has nested `p`. Rest should be picked up.