# ReactJs: How to escape <p> enclosing data rendering from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, escaping

How could I escape `<p>` enclosing data that are coming from Back-end in `props`.
I want to display my texts without this `<p>` enclosing tags around the texts.

ex:

```
props {
 explain: "`<p>`!! Check-in `</p>`"
}
```

how could i display this as

```
`props.explain` as "!! Check-in"
```

Any suggestions

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033905/regex-that-extracts-text-between-tags-but-not-the-tags

Comment: I think "escaping" is not the right term here, are the `<p>` rendering as p elements or text? If text, it means they are already "Escaped" (`<` replaced by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`)

Comment: Hi Tanmoy, Have you tried solution proposed with replace function?

Comment: @MaciejTrojniarz yes I am checking your solution. Thanks

Comment: @TanmoySarkar If your issue has been solved please mark the answer as the one that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prop would have name `explain` you can use regex:
`explain.replace(/<p[^>]*>|<\/p[^>]*>/g, "");`

so in react code you could use:

````js
render() {
  const { explain } = this.props
  return (
    { explain.replace(/<p[^>]*>|<\/p[^>]*>/g, "") }
  )
}```
````

Answer (score 2):

The proper way would be to remove the html tags from backend. However if you can't do that:

```
myVariable.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "")
```

It would remove all the html tags from a given string.